VBA code that allows multiple inputs in Userform
This may sound confusing, but I hope you'll bear with me. I have a user form for data entry which has a textbox designated for employee ids and various combo boxes which is designated for their demographics. Is it possible to create a vba code that allows me to input multiple employee ids in the textbox, and whatever information that will be answered to each combo boxes will be applied to all of the employee ids?


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, msg As String
    
    'check for any empty required fields
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Employee ID"

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then 'anything missing?
        MsgBox "The following fields are required:" & msg, _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Information"
    Else
        'OK to write to sheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Information")
        With sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .Resize(1, 12).Value = Array(TextBox1.Value, ComboBox1.Value, _
                                  ComboBox2.Value, ComboBox3.Value, ComboBox4.Value, _
                                  ComboBox5.Value, ComboBox6.Value, ComboBox7.Value, _
                                  ComboBox8.Value, ComboBox9.Value, ComboBox10.Value, _
                                  ComboBox11.Value)

     MsgBox "Employee Information Added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "ERROR"
     
    Unload Me
        End With
    End If
End Sub


If you enter multiple id's separated by comma you could do something like this:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, msg As String, arr, c As Range, id
    
    'check for any empty required fields
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then msg = msg & vbLf & " - Employee ID"

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then 'anything missing?
        MsgBox "The following fields are required:" & msg, _
                vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Information"
    Else
        'OK to write to sheet
        Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Employee Information")
        Set c = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) '##start adding here
        arr = Split(TextBox1.Value, ",") '##split on comma to get an array
        For Each id In arr               '##loop over the array
            c.Resize(1, 12).Value = Array(Trim(id), ComboBox1.Value, _
                                  ComboBox2.Value, ComboBox3.Value, ComboBox4.Value, _
                                  ComboBox5.Value, ComboBox6.Value, ComboBox7.Value, _
                                  ComboBox8.Value, ComboBox9.Value, ComboBox10.Value, _
                                  ComboBox11.Value)
            Set c = c.Offset(1)          '##next output row
        Next id

        MsgBox "Employee Information Added", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "ERROR"
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub


Hello Tim, this works to what I would like to do! Thank you so much! Can I also ask for some help to have a code for one of the combo boxes? The options that I would like to have for the combo box are the days from Monday to Sunday. When the user choose Saturday, I would like to duplicate the row and delete any other contents except for the employee ID and replace the saturday with sunday. Please see the additional Photo above.

That sounds like a different question...
